# Deleting the text preceeding a given sentence

Tags: python, file, text, file-io, data-analysis

I'm working on a file containing lot of biological data, my input file looks like,

```
Start
blah
blah
blah
blah
blah
5'UTR
IMPORTANT STRING
blah
blah
//

Start
blah
blah
blah
5'UTR
IMPORTANT STRING
blah
blah
blah
//
```

.... and so on this occurs for around 4k times. Now the challenge is to check if the important string contains "NO information", if it does delete the entire paragraph  (from Start to //) if not write the entire thing into a new file.

The problem i'm facing is that "5'UTR" is not recognised as a keyword when i do,
    for keyword in line
Also i can't seem to delete the entire paragraph.
How do i write a functional code in python

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to do exactly and I read your post 5 times already, maybe it's just me...

Comment: Writing the desired paragraphs into a new file is fairly easy. Deleting undesired paragraphs from your input file while you're reading it is hard, but I don't understand why you want to do that, since when you've finished processing the input file, the new file will contain only the desired paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading in the whole file and performing a regex on it, I'd read it in chunks, one record at a time, and `yield` it. Yield is Python's way of efficiently only evaluating a sequence as it's needed.

```
def records(stream):
    while stream:
        lines = []
        for line in stream:
            lines.append(line)
            if line.startswith('//'):
                break
        record = ''.join(lines)
        yield record

for record in records(data):
    if "5'UTR\nNO information" not in record:
        output.write(record)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will create a new `output.txt` file containing just the blocks which do not have the `NO information` line:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    text = f_input.read()
    blocks = re.findall(r"^(Start.*?^\/\/\n*)", text, re.M+re.S)
    blocks = [block for block in blocks if re.search(r"5'UTR\n(?!NO information).*?\n", block, re.M+re.S)]
    f_output.write("".join(blocks))
```

For your example `output.txt` will be the same as the input. It first creates a list of all of the blocks. It then filters out any which have `NO information` and then writes all of the remaining blocks to a new file.

Comment: Reading the whole file into RAM to process it is fast (although regex tends to be slower than equivalent `str` methods for simple tasks). However, if Advait has a **lot** of biological data to process it may not be practical to read it all in at once.